# Making CSS changes to (index)?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm currently trying to make some CSS changes to a WordPress child theme.

When I use the chrome developer tool, it tells me which line in the style.css file the elements refer to. For example, style.css:17.

However, on certain CSS elements, instead of referring to style.css it refers to (index). For example, (index):54. What does (index) refer to and where would I normally find it to make the changes?

Thanks

Comment: I think it's because style is apply directly to html tag

Comment: I thought that too, but I didn't see style changes in any html file.

Comment: Have you look if style tag is not present in the template of your page ?

Comment: Styles may have been added dynamically via scripts. Keep in mind styles can be **internal** `<style>` or **inline** `<div style="...">`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wordpress theme options usually appends a stylesheet to the head of the html document.

```
<head>
  <!-- added by Wordpress, usually found in functions.php -->
  <style>
    ...theme specific styles...
  </style>
</head>
```